# How to send and receive sms using sms lib api

Tags: java, smslib

i m new to sms lib api i never used api's before please would you give me some help how to use it from strart to end for sending and receiving sms using Gsm modem in eclipse. please it is an emergency my final year project is based upon it. please it will be a great favour..thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried looking for some tutorials on this topic?

Comment: yes i looked upon them but can't find any usefull help regarding this.

Comment: Could you post what you tried?

Comment: i read the complete documention of SMSLIB API but can't find any solution i have the code of SMSLIB API for sending and receiving SMS using GSM modem but don't have any idea how to use it.....

Comment: If you have tried something, edit your original post and published what you've tried and what errors/issue came up. Otherwise, you show no research effort. This is not a 'write my code for me' site.

Comment: @Howard, hardly comparable. The one you linked to asks a specific question, not (unlike here) how to write a HW task from scratch.
(BTW, I usually do not vote down or for closing but rather ask the user to show a minimal research effort.)

Answer (score 6):

**Assumption:**

- You have `java1.5` or higher installed on your Computer
- You are on `Windows OS`
- Your java installtion directory `JAVA_HOME` = `c:\java\jdk1.5`
- You have no separate `jre` installed on your pc ( you are using `jre` that is loacated at
  `JAVA_HOME\jre`)
- You have any java supported mobile phone,

Here we will connect PC with any java supported mobile via "Standard Serial Over blue tooth link".

**STEP 1.** Download `SMSLib` src from [here](http://code.google.com/p/smslib/downloads/list)

**STEP 2.** Download `RXTX` from [here](http://rxtx.qbang.org/pub/rxtx/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2.zip).

**STEP 3.** Download `CommonsNet` from [here](http://commons.apache.org/downloads/download_net.cgi).

**STEP 4.** Download `javacomm20-win32` from [here](http://smslib.googlecode.com/files/javacomm20-win32.zip).

**STEP 5.** Download `slf4j-1.5.6` from [here](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html).

**STEP 6.** Download `log4j-1.2.8.jar` from [here](http://logging.eu.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html).

**STEP 7.** Unzip all the files in suitable location

**STEP 8.** Copy following files to `JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\ext`

1. `commons-net-2.0.jar` from `CommonsNet\commons-net-2.0.jar`
2. `comm.jar` from `javacomm20-win32\commapi\comm.jar`
3. `javax.comm.properties` from `javacomm20-win32\commapi\javax.comm.properties`
4. `RXTXcomm.jar` from `rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2\RXTXcomm.jar`
5. All the jar from `slf4j-1.5.6\*.jar`
6. `smslib-3.4.1.jar` from `smslib-v3.4.1-bin\dist\lib\smslib-3.4.1.jar`

**STEP 9.** Copy following files to `JAVA_HOME\jre\bin`

1. `win32com.dll` from `javacomm20-win32\commapi\win32com.dll`
2. `rxtxSerial.dll` from `rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2\Windows\i368-mingw32\rxtxSerial.dll`
3. `rxtxParallel.dll` from `rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2\Windows\i368-mingw32\rxtxParallel.dll`

**STEP 10.** Copy following files to `C:\Program Files\WINDOWS\system32`

1. `win32com.dll` from `javacomm20-win32\commapi\win32com.dll`
2. `rxtxSerial.dll` from `rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2\Windows\i368-mingw32\rxtxSerial.dll`
3. `rxtxParallel.dll` from `rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2\Windows\i368-mingw32\rxtxParallel.dll`

**STEP 11.** If you are using any java IDE (i.e netbeans) then create new project, add source packages `smslib-v3.4.1-src\src\java`. You need to have all the file of **STEP 8** in your class path.(to compile the project) and build project. Set `misc.CommTest` as main class of the project.

**STEP 12.** Connect Bluetooth device to your computer's USB port. If PC prompts you for driver installation then install the driver. If your PC can not find any suitable driver the get the
driver from some where for Standard Serial Link Over Bluetooth

**STEP 13.** Once the driver is installed start Bluetooth of mobile phone.

**STEP 14**. Open control panel --> BueTooth Device

- click add
- check 'select passkey for me'
- click next
- system will display pass key
- accept connection from mobile phone using that pass key(allow connections without prompt)

**STEP 15.** Open control panel/Phone and modem You should see one modem attached to port like '`COM5`' in modem list.

STEP 16. Run `misc.CommTest` and wait for program to complete. When program completes, Note-down for which values of `baud rate` and `comm port`. The program will print text like below:

```
Getting Info :
(some text)(model name of us phone) i.e (Some text)Nokia7210 Suppernova.
You have to note values for the com port attached to your modem in modem list ( comtrol panel /phone and modem)
```

**STEP 17.** Open `examples.modem.SendMessage.java` file in your IDE and modefy following line according to your environment.

```
SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com1", "COM1", 57600, "Nokia", "6310i");
```

1. First arg = here first argument of the `SerialModemGateway()` constructor can be any String
2. 2nd Arg = com port (port attached to your modem in modem list (control panel /phone and modem))
3. 3rd arg = baud rate for which commtest got info(refer to step 16)
4. 4rth arg = manufacturer of your mobile phone i.e Nokia , SAMSUNG
5. 5th arg = Model name of your mobile phone (refer to step 16)

Modify following line

```
msg = new OutboundMessage("+00123456567889", "Hello from SMSLib!");
here replace +00123456567889 with +<your number with ISD code>
```

add following line some where after instantiation of `SerialModemGateway`

```
gateway.setSMSCNumber("+919825068000")
```

This smsc number can be found from you mobile's 'Message'/'Message Settings' depending on your mobile phone software

**STEP 18.** Run `examples.modem.SendMessage`.

Source: http://sendsmsusingsmslib.blogspot.in/

Comment: thanks shishir sir  for your help i m doing this if i found any kind of problems i will contact with you agin.

Comment: sir i actually tried your code when i execute the step no 16 instead of showing the correct result the error i m facing is the following i m using netbeans 8.0 error is                                  run:
C:\Users\SanaUllah Amin Malik\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:48: 
Cancelled by user.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: @Sanaullah did you solve your problem? were you able to send sms?