# Windows - Extract text from SMS using D-LINK DWM-157

Tags: database, windows, sms

My Industrial Engineering final year project is based upon a weight scale that measures LPG content inside a cylinder, and relays this information to consumers and refillers via SMS.

The SMS reads as follows:

Total Weight: 7.705 kg
LPG Weight: 3.305 kg
LPG Remaining: 82.621%
Wednesday 07.03.2018 -- 17:16:03

I have a D-LINK DWM-157 plugged into my computer, where the SMS messages are received in D-LINK's software. I need to somehow extract the contents of these messages and process/store them in a database.

I personally have minimal programming experience, so I need advice on how to extract this SMS data for further processing.

Comment: I hope you have a lot of time left for this project if you do indeed have minimal programming experience ;-)  I have about 5 years experience doing what you're wanting to do.  You basically need to use AT commands to communicate with the device se an example here [dlink dwm-157 extra operator report during each operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330341/dlink-dwm-157-extra-operator-report-during-each-operation) I've used [SMSLib](https://github.com/tdelenikas/smslib) with great success, it's java based.

Comment: SMSLib basically creates a serial connection to the device, then can send and receive SMS using the AT commands.  This SO article [how to send and receive sms using sms lib api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587568/how-to-send-and-receive-sms-using-sms-lib-api)

If this helps you get up and going, let me know and I can put it all together for an answer for you as well as others.

Comment: Did this help you out at all?